# Why does an uncountable well-ordered set exist?

Tags: set-theory

A well-ordered set $(W, <)$ is a set $W$ with a total order $<$ such that every nonempty subset of $W$ has a minimal element.

Let $(W, <)$ be an infinite well-ordered set.

Define a sequence $ w_0 = \min W$, $ w_{i+1} = \min(W \setminus \bigcup_{j=1}^i \{ w_j \})$ (the minimas exist $\forall i$ since $W$ is infinite), then

$$ W = \{ w_i : i \in \mathbb N_0 \}$$

because the $w_i$ just go through $W$ from the „smallest“ element to the „second smallest“ and so on, hence every element in $W$ is reached.

Hence, $W$ is countable. Of course, there has to be a mistake in this proof since there are uncountable well-ordered sets. But where is the mistake?

Answer (score 4):

The assertion that $W=\{w_i\,:\, i\in \Bbb N_0\}$ is false, and it's already false for almost all countable ordinals: for instance, $W=\{\infty\}\cup\{0,1,2,\cdots\}$, with $x\le \infty$ for all $x\in W$, will result in $w_i=i$, and therefore $W\setminus\{w_i\,:\, i\in\Bbb N_0\}=\{\infty\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, you cannot ensure every element in $W$ is reached. Just for $W=\mathbb{Z}_+\times \mathbb{Z}_+,$ having lexicographical order. Which means $(a,b)<(c,d)\Leftrightarrow a<c$ or $a=c$ but $b<d.$

So the smallest one is $(1,1)$, then $(1,2),$ $\cdots$ However, by this way you can only count $(1,n).$ Not for whole $W$ acutually.